# Why does Windows have issues with the encoding, but Linux doesn't?

Tags: windows, encoding, python-3.6

For my toy project [`mpu`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu) I have two CI solutions running:

- [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/github/MartinThoma/mpu) / Linux: Works
- [Azure](https://dev.azure.com/martinthoma/mpu/_build/results?buildId=11&view=logs&j=19c563d8-3dcd-57d1-cd5e-9dd946b0a29b&t=c276ab56-9c7b-560d-e018-453666437518) / Windows: Fails

It fails with this message:

```
_______________________________ test_read_json ________________________________

    def test_read_json():
        path = "files/example.json"
        source = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, path)
        data_real = read(source)
    
        data_exp = {
            "a list": [1, 42, 3.141, 1337, "help", "�"],
            "a string": "bla",
            "another dict": {"foo": "bar", "key": "value", "the answer": 42},
        }
>       assert data_real == data_exp
E       AssertionError: assert {'a list': [1... answer': 42}} == {'a list': [1... answer': 42}}
E         Omitting 2 identical items, use -vv to show
E         Differing items:
E         {'a list': [1, 42, 3.141, 1337, 'help', '€']} != {'a list': [1, 42, 3.141, 1337, 'help', '�']}
E         Use -v to get the full diff

tests\test_io.py:175: AssertionError
```

Why can it read the € sign from the JSON, but within the test it fails? (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the `read` function which is used in the test wraps `open` in some way or another.

TL;DR Try adding **`encoding='utf8'`** to the call to `open`.

From my experience, Windows does not always play nice with non-ascii characters when reading files unless the encoding is set explicitly.

Also, it does not help that [the default value for `encoding` is platform-dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> encoding is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the
> file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is
> platform dependent (whatever [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns),
> but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the codecs
> module for the list of supported encodings.

some tests (ran on Win 10, Python 3.7,  `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns `cp1262`):

test.csv

```
€
```

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    print(f.read())

# â‚¬

with open('test.csv', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read())

# '€'
```

Comment: The default encoding in Windows is the process active codepage, from WinAPI `GetACP()`. In Windows 10, this can be set to UTF-8 at either the system level or in the application manifest with the ["activeCodePage"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) setting. For the latter, one has to modify the embedded manifest in the application executable (e.g. "python[w].exe"). Python 3.7+ also allows overriding the platform default by enabling [UTF-8 mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUTF8).

Comment: The problem with hard-coding `utf8` as the encoding in `open` is that on Windows you're less likely to have UTF-8 files.  Anything created with native Windows software will likely use the default code page unless you've taken care to specify otherwise.

Comment: P.S. to let Python use the Windows default code page, use `encoding='mbcs'`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, "mbcs" uses the process active codepage, from `GetACP()`, which isn't necessarily the system default if the active codepage is set to UTF-8 in the application manifest. Newer versions of the CRT also use "utf8" as the locale encoding if the process active codepage is UTF-8, overriding the legacy codepage of the per-user locale, which accounts for programs that use the CRT locale and/or get the encoding to use from `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`. As long as people keep avoiding UTF-8 as a default encoding in Windows, legacy encodings will never become a footnote in history.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks for filling in those details.  I'm all for using UTF-8 as a default for output, but using it as a default for input will cause nothing but heartache until Microsoft gets with the times and makes it system-wide.  Legacy encodings will be with us for a long time I'm afraid.

Comment: @MarkRansom,  I don't think Microsoft is in a position to force its customers to use UTF-8. All I expect is the ability to set UTF-8 as the system default and the ability for an application to override the default to use UTF-8. They've already implemented both in Windows 10. Now it's up to system administrators and/or applications to embrace change.